# Ajax vs submit - why don't I get the same response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, post

I am using Ajax to submit this. All variables ending in **box are global**.

**Not the full code, rest assured the other part such as the init is working.**

```
function begin() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed. This is completely up to you and all consequences go towards you!!"))
    {
        var usernameName = usernameBox.getAttribute("name");
        var passwordName = passwordBox.getAttribute("name");
        var hiddenName = hiddenBox.getAttribute("name");
        var username = usernameBox.value;
        var password = passwordBox.value;
        var hidden = hiddenBox.value;
        if (username !== "" && password !== "")
        {
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open("POST", "<?php echo $url_base, $action?>");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                console.log(http.readyState + " " + http.status);
                if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
                {
                    alert(http.responseText);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("We had an error!!!");
                }
            }
            var query = hiddenName + "=" + hidden + "&" + usernameName + "=" + username + "&" + passwordName + "=" + password;
            //var query = usernameName + "=" + username + "&" + passwordName + "=" + password;
            console.log(query);
            http.send(query);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("don't be a fool fill out the info");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No refunds!!");
    }
}
```

The form is below. This form works perfectly when I use a submit instead of the `onclick` and then use Ajax, any particular reason as to why. Could it potentially be the form name. I don't have access to the server if you are wondering.

> ```
> <form name="signin_form" action="<?php echo $url_base,$action?>" method="post">
> <input id='hidden' type="hidden" name="loginPage" value="student">
> <label>Username <input id='userid' size="25" name="student_userid" tabindex="0"><br/></label>
> <label> Password<input id='password' type="password" size="25" name="student_password"></br></label>
> <input id='submit' style="COLOR: #6373b5" type="button" value="Sign In" width="100px" onclick="begin();">
> </form>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything particularly wrong in your code. The Form name isn't passed anyway.

Have you checked to make sure the requests are identical with http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ or http://www.charlesproxy.com/? Those tools automatically create local proxy servers on your machine that capture and display web requests and responses as they occur. Just fire up the tool and then try the request in the browser and you'll see the raw request/response pair.

Make sure the [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), headers, and bodies match up.

It's possible [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is adding some extra headers, and the server code is doing something different based on them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but don't really know what fiddler is. I read the link but still confused. Is there a tutorial or anything?

Comment: Both of those tools automatically create local proxy servers on your machine that capture and display web requests and responses as they occur. Just fire up the tool and then try the request in the browser and you'll see the raw request/response pair in Fiddler or Charles. Help is here: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/